# Jquery:Sum values of checkbox on same row to textfield on same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some checkboxes with values which need sum up. When the checkboxes are checked the values get added in an array and displayed. Here is a demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/maxwellpayne/gKWmB/
However when I go to a new row it continues summing my values instead of starting afresh emptying the array on row change.The HTML code is long so please view it at the link provided.

Here is the jquery code summing them up:

```
var total_array = new Array();
var total_amount = 0;
$("#dailyexpense input[type=checkbox]:checked ").live('change', function() {

    var check_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var valu = $(this).val();
    $("#tdtotals input[type=text]").each(function() {
        totals_id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (totals_id == check_id) {
            total_array.push(valu);
            total_amount = eval(total_array.join('+')).toFixed(2);
            $(this).val(total_amount);
        }

    });
});
```

All help will be appreciated

PS: However is editing the code in jsfiddle and distorting everything, stop it.

Comment: Maybe not what you want to hear, but you have another bug - unchecking a checkbox doesn't subtract from its value, thus if you uncheck and recheck, the sum will go up.
Why not just use `.each` whenever a checkbox is changed, re-calculate the whole line and put the correct sum in the text box? That should solve both problems...

Comment: @EranZimmerman - what a great idea!

Comment: Hey Eran, thanks for pointing out that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gKWmB/3/

Basically we rethink the structure. If a checkbox value changes we get its parent row. Then we find all checkboxes in that row. Finally we total them and display.

```
//watch checkboxes
$('tr input[type=checkbox]').change( function(){   
  var total = 0;
  //total all sibling checkboxes
  $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each( function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());        
  });

  //display the result
  $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=text]:last').val(total);
});
```

Comment: I also want to say since my table has repeating rows using clone, modifying the $('tr input[type=checkbox]').change( function().... to $('tr input[type=checkbox]').live('change', function()... reflects changes on newly created rows.